# How to lure a escaped snake

Tags: snakes

Is quite a bizarre situation, it is a not poisonous, not dangerous for human/children 1,5 m rat snake. We have two snakes in a terrarium in the living room. and now one of then managed to escape...
We already turn the house completely upside down, but we can't find him. We realize it will, most likely, look for a dark, warm spot, so we tried to checked all of these we could imagine in the house..

We fed the snakes dead mice and/or chicken, the last time we fed them was 1,5 week ago.

I would like to get the best suggestions/tips/tricks about how to attract/lure/trap a snakes as described.  (if ours it is still in the house. :-) )